# Angular2 , How to find index of a view inside a viewContianer

Tags: angular

Let's say using I have a directive that can load components dynamically in it's viewContianerRef :

```
@Directive( { selector : '[loader-ref]' } )
export class LoaderDirective {
    constructor ( private cd : ChangeDetectorRef ,
                  private viewContainer : ViewContainerRef ,
                  private componentResolver : ComponentResolver ) {
    }
    getIndexOf(viewRef:ViewRef){

       return this.viewContainer.indexOf(viewRef);
    }
    createComponent ( dialogComponent : { new() : any } ) : Promise<ComponentRef<any>> {
        return this.componentResolver
                   .resolveComponent( dialogComponent )
                   .then( ( componentFactory : ComponentFactory<any> ) => {
                       return this.viewContainer.createComponent( componentFactory );
                   } );
    }
}
```

My component that should be loaded dynamically :

```
@Component({
  selector:'my-dynamic-component'
})
export class myDynamicComponent{

   // Is there any way to get this component's ViewRef , or HostView? 


}
```

And I'm using LoaderDirective to load a component dynamically like this :

My App :

```
@Component( {
    selector   : 'example' ,
    template:` <button (click)='getIndex()'></button> <div loader-ref></div>`
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    @ViewChild( LoaderDirective ) loaderDirective : LoaderDirective;


    ngOnInit(){
         let waitForChunk = require( 'myDynamicComponent.ts' );
    waitForChunk( ( file ) => {
        this.loaderDirective
            .createComponent( file[ 'default' ] )
            .then( ( componentRef : ComponentRef<any> ) => {
                componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
            } );
    } );

    }


    getIndex(){
         // Here I want to get index of myDynamicComponent which is loaded 
        ////What do I need to do ?   ??
         let index = this.loaderDirective.getIndexOf(what to pass ? )

         console.log('My index is : '+index);

    }
}
```

This is working , but know my question :

Inside my directive , I have a viewContainerRef , which has a method called [`indexOf`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#indexOf-anchor) .

This method is supposed to return the index of the loaded component inside the viewContainerRef , but I don't know how it works and how to use it :

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for `hostView` property of [ComponentRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentRef-class.html)

```
loadedView: ViewRef;
...
  this.loaderDirective
    .createComponent(myDynamicComponent)
    .then((componentRef: ComponentRef<any>) => {
      componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      this.loadedView = componentRef.hostView; <== this line
    });
...
getIndex(){
  let index = this.loaderDirective.getIndexOf(this.loadedView);
  console.log('My index is : '+index);
}
```

But in your case it will always be equals 0 because you're firing:

```
this.viewContainer.clear();
```

See also **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/juBRbHXCP3cXXCi6G6Dm?p=preview)** for **angular2 2.0.0**

**Update1**

if you want to have access to view inside the `myDynamicComponent` directive then you can leverage the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dynamic-component'
})
export class myDynamicComponent {
  public view: ViewRef;
}

...
 this.loaderDirective
    .createComponent(myDynamicComponent)
    .then((componentRef: ComponentRef<any>) => {
      componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      componentRef.instance.view = componentRef.hostView; <== add this line
    });
```

I updated **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/juBRbHXCP3cXXCi6G6Dm?p=preview)**

**Update2**

You can also to get viewRef this way:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

...
var viewRef = this.injector._view.ref;
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/juBRbHXCP3cXXCi6G6Dm?p=preview)**

But in this case you will use private propery of `Injector`. **It's bad practice.**

Comment: Your solution is working , but Is there any way to access to viewRef ( hostView) inside the myDynamicComponent ?

Comment: This only work if I have loaded only one component and it'll always be 0. But I need to be able to load multiple components and then  get indexOf them afterward

Comment: Nice , this absolutely works, But is this the only way to get a reference to `hostView ( viewRef )` inside my component ? What if the component hasn't been loaded this way? Shouldn't it be a proper way inside the component , like injecting something ? ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an access to ViewRef inside your component , one possible solution might be :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dynamic-component'
})
export class myDynamicComponent implements OnInit {
  public view: ViewRef;
  constructor(private _viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef){

  }

  ngOnInit(){

   console.log('ViewRef',this._viewContainerRef._element.parentView.ref);
 }
}
```

Looks a bit hacky , but it works.

Comment: This works, but do you think there might any side effects ?