# How to remove component dynamically in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am using this method to remove a component `ViewContainerRef.remove(index: number)` however, with this way, I need to work out the component index. My question is:

If I use `ViewContainerRef.remove` to remove a component, what is the best way to find the component index?

Any alternative ways for removing components?

Comment: How about using `*ngIf` in template?

Comment: The components are added dynamically so you can't use *ngIf

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552953/angular2-how-to-find-index-of-a-view-inside-a-viewcontianer/39555982 for an example.